# CutyCapt not working

Tags: segmentation-fault, cutycapt

CutyCapt is working great but is failing for just 1 site, out of many:

This:
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1280x768x24"  --auto-servernum /usr/local/bin/CutyCapt --url=http://www.boden.co.uk/ --out=/var/www/screentest/test.png

Results in:
Segmentation Fault.

Any ideas?

It's a Debian box, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed the same problem with some pages. However, that I noticed it "sometimes" does work even for these pages. Don't ask me when and why :)! I therefore have added a loop to my bash script that tries multiple times - see below the snippet of the code - before finally giving up. You might want to try something similar.

```
try=1
while [[ ! -f tmp.jpg ]]
do
   cutycapt --url=example.org --out=tmp.jpg
   let try=try+1
   if [ $try -gt 100 ]; then
      exit 0
fi
done
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Did the work for you in the end? As I said, I don't know why it works :).